# RS485 interface in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, reader, rs485

I would like to access a reader from my Raspberry PI. It is connected to my Raspberry PI via an Ethernet cable and has an RS485 interface.

Can anyone help me accomplish this task and suggest me steps to establish communication between the devices?

I searched for answers to this problem and I expect some information.

Comment: If you have connected a RS-485 port to the Pi's Ethernet port, it is not going to work. Even though the two are both able to use the RJ-45 connector, the protocols are different. To communicate using RS-485 from a Pi, you need an RS-485 driver. These are sold in a convenient form factor for the Raspberry Pi as hats.

Comment: I'm voting to close this since it is a hardware question related to programming. You could ask at electronics.stackexchange.com but then you need to add way more details. Or in case the question is about some Rasp Pi-specific board, ask it on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

> It is connected to my Raspberry PI via an Ethernet cable and has an
> RS485 interface.

Do not connect RS485 to the Ethernet port of your PI. You may fry the port.

To use the RS-485 interface with your PI you need RS-485 hat (addon card) which has RS485 transceiver:

[image]

https://thepihut.com/products/rs422-rs485-serial-hat

Comment: This might be correct, but it still doesn't make the question on-topic. Questions and answers here should be about programming.